# Can't seem to uninstall scala with Homebrew

Tags: scala, homebrew

I'm trying to uninstall scala so I can redownload an older version for compatibility reasons. I thought I had done it but whenever I run scala, it still runs the latest version, the one I thought I had uninstalled. This is the code I've been running in my terminal, I'm on a macbook also, anymore info needed lmk, any help is much appreciated!

➜  ~ scala
Welcome to Scala 3.2.0 (18.0.2.1, Java Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :q

➜  ~ brew list scala
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/scala

➜  ~ brew uninstall scala
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/scala

Comment: Are you sure you installed using `brew`? What does `which scala` say?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure I did, this is what the code outputted
➜  ~ which scala
/Users/scottmaxwell/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin/scala

Comment: Looks like you used `coursier` rather than `brew` to install it, so maybe `cs uninstall scala scalac`?

Comment: That worked! Don't know how that happened, thanks for the help! Getting another issue now, whenever I install scala@2.11 on brew I get this error,
Error: scala@2.11 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!
Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: That's a very old version, latest is `2.13.10`

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much again! Lifesaver!

Comment: great! been looking for ways to uninstall scala 3 on my machine, it worked!